# HTML CSS Increase size of background image so it grows with the text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a background images I am using and the issue I am running into is that as the screen size get smaller the text runs off the image. What can I do from a responsive design stand point so that the background image grows with the text?

Here is a link to jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jUr9E/640/

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered"><p>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat a eros ut fermentum. Cras interdum nisl mollis felis dignissim efficitur. Sed viverra auctor velit eu ullamcorper. Quisque at lectus quis eros efficitur venenatis. Proin vestibulum odio ex. Cras euismod varius diam, laoreet dapibus urna bibendum a. In eget tincidunt ligula.

Ut placerat, nisl euismod aliquet lacinia, velit eros dignissim arcu, ut maximus tellus metus a justo. Sed ut purus vitae eros efficitur iaculis at iaculis lectus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus pretium sagittis ex vitae luctus. Suspendisse tincidunt turpis quis nunc iaculis, ut suscipit ipsum ornare. Donec vehicula est metus, sed luctus urna tempus ut. Aliquam lorem ante, dictum in augue ac, venenatis iaculis sem. Donec diam justo, auctor fringilla augue a, interdum imperdiet purus. Pellentesque commodo luctus magna, eget tincidunt odio placerat quis. Cras interdum est ac justo hendrerit dapibus. Quisque non diam vitae orci cursus ornare vel vel mauris. Sed eleifend cursus laoreet.

Proin quis est consequat velit efficitur cursus at ut nunc. Pellentesque sed commodo nulla. Nam tristique ultrices pretium. Aenean accumsan aliquam sodales. Aenean ut nisi justo. Curabitur vulputate justo vitae erat accumsan facilisis. Cras aliquet nisl vel neque rutrum, id mattis erat ultrices. Ut vel sapien id magna aliquam varius. Nulla magna ex, convallis ut vulputate eget, porta vitae augue. Sed ut odio id augue fermentum porttitor.

Vestibulum egestas felis tellus, sed dapibus massa dictum a. Aliquam justo lorem, efficitur lacinia ligula ut, vestibulum vulputate mauris. Aenean eget urna felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. In imperdiet sem sem, eget bibendum tortor tincidunt eu. Donec semper rutrum est, eget volutpat ex blandit quis. Mauris dignissim quam a felis aliquam accumsan. Maecenas dictum turpis justo, blandit auctor purus condimentum ac.

Nullam cursus lorem non ultricies tempor. Maecenas convallis nulla vel ex maximus, vitae sagittis leo pretium. Proin aliquet elementum erat, non rhoncus dolor eleifend eget. Nulla imperdiet lorem sit amet laoreet sagittis. Sed vulputate dictum dui sit amet lobortis. Ut et vehicula nisi. Fusce eu enim nec nisi egestas placerat. Sed tempus tincidunt eros, a mattis enim hendrerit et. Nunc dolor ipsum, varius et enim quis, semper luctus nulla. Aenean pharetra, justo quis volutpat efficitur, nulla turpis consequat nulla, nec cursus enim eros quis sem. Donec vitae interdum sem. Etiam faucibus nisi at dui congue, id tempus tortor efficitur. Quisque rhoncus eget lorem ut consectetur. Maecenas dapibus laoreet dignissim. Aliquam eu est accumsan neque aliquet tristique ut vitae libero.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat a eros ut fermentum. Cras interdum nisl mollis felis dignissim efficitur. Sed viverra auctor velit eu ullamcorper. Quisque at lectus quis eros efficitur venenatis. Proin vestibulum odio ex. Cras euismod varius diam, laoreet dapibus urna bibendum a. In eget tincidunt ligula.

Ut placerat, nisl euismod aliquet lacinia, velit eros dignissim arcu, ut maximus tellus metus a justo. Sed ut purus vitae eros efficitur iaculis at iaculis lectus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus pretium sagittis ex vitae luctus. Suspendisse tincidunt turpis quis nunc iaculis, ut suscipit ipsum ornare. Donec vehicula est metus, sed luctus urna tempus ut. Aliquam lorem ante, dictum in augue ac, venenatis iaculis sem. Donec diam justo, auctor fringilla augue a, interdum imperdiet purus. Pellentesque commodo luctus magna, eget tincidunt odio placerat quis. Cras interdum est ac justo hendrerit dapibus. Quisque non diam vitae orci cursus ornare vel vel mauris. Sed eleifend cursus laoreet.

Proin quis est consequat velit efficitur cursus at ut nunc. Pellentesque sed commodo nulla. Nam tristique ultrices pretium. Aenean accumsan aliquam sodales. Aenean ut nisi justo. Curabitur vulputate justo vitae erat accumsan facilisis. Cras aliquet nisl vel neque rutrum, id mattis erat ultrices. Ut vel sapien id magna aliquam varius. Nulla magna ex, convallis ut vulputate eget, porta vitae augue. Sed ut odio id augue fermentum porttitor.

Vestibulum egestas felis tellus, sed dapibus massa dictum a. Aliquam justo lorem, efficitur lacinia ligula ut, vestibulum vulputate mauris. Aenean eget urna felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. In imperdiet sem sem, eget bibendum tortor tincidunt eu. Donec semper rutrum est, eget volutpat ex blandit quis. Mauris dignissim quam a felis aliquam accumsan. Maecenas dictum turpis justo, blandit auctor purus condimentum ac.

Nullam cursus lorem non ultricies tempor. Maecenas convallis nulla vel ex maximus, vitae sagittis leo pretium. Proin aliquet elementum erat, non rhoncus dolor eleifend eget. Nulla imperdiet lorem sit amet laoreet sagittis. Sed vulputate dictum dui sit amet lobortis. Ut et vehicula nisi. Fusce eu enim nec nisi egestas placerat. Sed tempus tincidunt eros, a mattis enim hendrerit et. Nunc dolor ipsum, varius et enim quis, semper luctus nulla. Aenean pharetra, justo quis volutpat efficitur, nulla turpis consequat nulla, nec cursus enim eros quis sem. Donec vitae interdum sem. Etiam faucibus nisi at dui congue, id tempus tortor efficitur. Quisque rhoncus eget lorem ut consectetur. Maecenas dapibus laoreet dignissim. Aliquam eu est accumsan neque aliquet tristique ut vitae libero.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat a eros ut fermentum. Cras interdum nisl mollis felis dignissim efficitur. Sed viverra auctor velit eu ullamcorper. Quisque at lectus quis eros efficitur venenatis. Proin vestibulum odio ex. Cras euismod varius diam, laoreet dapibus urna bibendum a. In eget tincidunt ligula.

Ut placerat, nisl euismod aliquet lacinia, velit eros dignissim arcu, ut maximus tellus metus a justo. Sed ut purus vitae eros efficitur iaculis at iaculis lectus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus pretium sagittis ex vitae luctus. Suspendisse tincidunt turpis quis nunc iaculis, ut suscipit ipsum ornare. Donec vehicula est metus, sed luctus urna tempus ut. Aliquam lorem ante, dictum in augue ac, venenatis iaculis sem. Donec diam justo, auctor fringilla augue a, interdum imperdiet purus. Pellentesque commodo luctus magna, eget tincidunt odio placerat quis. Cras interdum est ac justo hendrerit dapibus. Quisque non diam vitae orci cursus ornare vel vel mauris. Sed eleifend cursus laoreet.

Proin quis est consequat velit efficitur cursus at ut nunc. Pellentesque sed commodo nulla. Nam tristique ultrices pretium. Aenean accumsan aliquam sodales. Aenean ut nisi justo. Curabitur vulputate justo vitae erat accumsan facilisis. Cras aliquet nisl vel neque rutrum, id mattis erat ultrices. Ut vel sapien id magna aliquam varius. Nulla magna ex, convallis ut vulputate eget, porta vitae augue. Sed ut odio id augue fermentum porttitor.

Vestibulum egestas felis tellus, sed dapibus massa dictum a. Aliquam justo lorem, efficitur lacinia ligula ut, vestibulum vulputate mauris. Aenean eget urna felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. In imperdiet sem sem, eget bibendum tortor tincidunt eu. Donec semper rutrum est, eget volutpat ex blandit quis. Mauris dignissim quam a felis aliquam accumsan. Maecenas dictum turpis justo, blandit auctor purus condimentum ac.

Nullam cursus lorem non ultricies tempor. Maecenas convallis nulla vel ex maximus, vitae sagittis leo pretium. Proin aliquet elementum erat, non rhoncus dolor eleifend eget. Nulla imperdiet lorem sit amet laoreet sagittis. Sed vulputate dictum dui sit amet lobortis. Ut et vehicula nisi. Fusce eu enim nec nisi egestas placerat. Sed tempus tincidunt eros, a mattis enim hendrerit et. Nunc dolor ipsum, varius et enim quis, semper luctus nulla. Aenean pharetra, justo quis volutpat efficitur, nulla turpis consequat nulla, nec cursus enim eros quis sem. Donec vitae interdum sem. Etiam faucibus nisi at dui congue, id tempus tortor efficitur. Quisque rhoncus eget lorem ut consectetur. Maecenas dapibus laoreet dignissim. Aliquam eu est accumsan neque aliquet tristique ut vitae libero.
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
.container{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:3000px;
    width:100%;

}

p{
 margin-top:10%; 
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}


.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: you have a fixed height, and the content is absolute so out of the flow ... keep the content inflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your css like this:

```
.container{
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
  background-color:#0C0C0C;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}

p{
   margin-top:10%; 

}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


.centered {
  text-align:center;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```